# LoadError in Devise::SessionsController#create -- cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext

Tags: bcrypt-ruby

I am getting the following error and I have no idea what to do.

I have tried all the available solutions on internet but I cannot get rid of this problem. I am attaching the screen shot of the error.

[image]

I am using mysql2, rails version is "Rails 5.0.1" and ruby version is "ruby 2.3.3p222".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the above issue by typing following commands:

```
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
```

after that we need to reinstall

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

now we need to add below code in the gem file

```
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby
```

by performing above steps bcrypt issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

1. `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby`
2. In your gemfile, add

   ```
   gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
   ```
3. `bundle install`

This works on Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions

run cmd with adminstrator priveleges and paste this.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

after you install windows build tools, you can use bcrypt without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below gems in the gemfile would resolve the issue:

```
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby # to resolve the cannot load such file -- sassc
gem "sassc-rails" # to resolve the cannot load such file -- sassc
```

Then:

```
 bundle install
 rails s
```